# Android 5.0.1 Не работает Background и theme

Tags: android, background, android-themes, android-ui

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> Style

```
<style name="MainAppTheme.FullScreen" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimaryDarkMainApp</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDarkMainApp</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorMainTextBlack</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/main_text_size</item>
    <item name="popupTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light</item>
    <item name="radioButtonStyle">@style/RadioButtonDialog</item>
</style>
```

> Layout.xml

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/login_faggot">

    <TextView
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Welcome."
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView10"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="152dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>
    <TextView
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textColor="@color/grayBg"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/plsLogin"
        android:text="Please Login."
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView10"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>

    <TextView
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView11"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/editLogin"
        android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/editPass"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/editLogin"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"/>
    <TextView
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView12"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/editPass"
        android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/editPass"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/editPass"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"/>
    <EditText
        android:paddingStart="20dp"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_mail_white_24dp"
        android:drawablePadding="15dp"
        android:hint="@string/user_name"
        android:id="@+id/editLogin"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/plsLogin"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"/>
    <EditText
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_lock_white_24dp"
        android:paddingStart="20dp"
        android:drawablePadding="15dp"
        android:hint="@string/password"
        android:id="@+id/editPass"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editLogin"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"/>

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/radioButton"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.CompoundButton.RadioButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingStart="15dp"
        android:text="Remember Me"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/editPass"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editPass"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonLogin"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/button_round_corner"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorOrangeUsSite"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:stateListAnimator="@null"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="@string/login"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/editPass"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/radioButton"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/radioButton"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutProgressBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:alpha="0.8"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
        <ProgressBar
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:theme="@style/ProgressBar"/>
    </FrameLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Я уже все перепробовал, но почему такая штука происходит не знаю. В интернете нет ничего подобного. Странно даже не то, что задний фон белый, а то, что картинки нет. *Background* почему-то белый.

Этoт баг появляется на Android 5.0.1. Проверял на Samsung S4. На других не проверял - нет других телефонов.

На реальном телефоне  6.0 и 7.0 тестировал - все нормально (нет никакого белого экрана)

---

Comment: покажите структуру папки res развернутую?

Comment: Добавил res развернутый

Comment: я к тому есть ли у вас разные drawable под разные dpi? и какое исходное разрешение изображения, которое хотите поставить на бэкграунд?

Comment: @LexHobbit, Вот добавил. login_faggot Он без dpi. Я его в drawable добавил в исходном видео.

Comment: а ответ на второй вопрос?

Comment: @LexHobbit, Кстати убрал я bakcround и в макете я увидел то что показывается в Android 5.0.1. Размер картинки 1080*1920 JPEG 24 bit 91.33 килобайт

Comment: @LexHobbit, Есть предложения почему так произошло?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63236/discussion-between-lex-hobbit-and-eranewgames).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мы с Lex Hobbit решили проблему. Вся проблема была в том что из за большого файла Android не сжимал картинку. Всем спасибо за помощь

Comment: Всё перепробовал, думал что ситуация безнадёжная. Потом прочитал комментарий, что может быть изза большого файла, вставил меньшую картинку и ВУАЛЯ. Дай тебе бог здоровья, добрый человек